# How to set up a domain network for 3 computers

Tags: networking, windows, xubuntu, home-directory

I am fairly new to linux and so would like to get some information on setting up my home network.  It will consist of three computers.  The Ubuntu server, a desktop running Ubuntu, and a desktop running Windows.  I am not too sure if I am using the correct terminology here, but I want the network to be a domain network.  I.E. when I boot up a computer, I want to put in my username and password and have access to the same files/configuration as if I logged onto the other computer.  I need to have about 5 different sets of users on this network.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you would need an authentication service that works for both Linux and Windows and then a way to share files across either Windows or Linux with your home directory mounted automatically (potentially on login) and a roaming profile shared out for the windows machine.

File sharing is the easy part.  Samba and NFS.  NFS to share files to the Linux machine and Samba to share files to the windows machine.  Though you could use Samba for both, I guess.

As a starting point, you could check out [Open LDAP](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html) for authentication.

I'm not sure about configuring the windows machine to authenticate against LDAP, perhaps you have to use samba for [that](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Windows7), too... otherwise you may have to install additional software in windows to enable it to authenticate against LDAP (such as [pGina](http://pgina.org/)).

There are various [guides](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_%26_LDAP) with varying levels of user-friendliness.

I hope this is a starting point, at least.  I've not had to do this sort of set up in a very long time, so I'm afraid I wont be of much help other than what little info I've provided here.